# jquery in Spring MVC

Tags: spring-mvc

I need some help to import jquery in my spring MVC project that can work offline.

```
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/bootstrap.min.js" />"></script>
<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" />"></script>
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/font-awesome-4.5.0/css/font-awesome.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="<c:url value="/resources/css/bootstrap.css" />" rel="stylesheet">
```

these are some css and js in my project  css is working fine even bootstrap js is also working but problem is with the jquery-1.11.1.min.js .
if I import it online like `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>` then it works fine but not working when i import it from my saved location like `<script src="<c:url value="/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js" />"></script>`.

my dispatcher servlet code is

```
 <bean id="tilesConfigurer" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesConfigurer">
    <property name="definitions">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/ApacheTiles/tiles.xml</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="viewResolver" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
    <property name="viewClass" value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.tiles3.TilesView" />
</bean>

<mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources" />
<mvc:annotation-driven/>
```

Comment: where do you put the jquery.js file locally in your source code? Where does it come up in the generated war file

Comment: First of all you can try from the internet explorer, by giving the URL's to the resources in order to check that are you able to access them. For example: http://localhost:8080/MyApp/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js   You can try downloading other resources also like bootstrap.min.js. Share your results which one you are able to download. Seems to me problem with jquery file name, you can rename  it like jquery.js and try again

Comment: Hey #abdulrafique i have done all these things already (http://localhost:8080/SMS/resources/js/jquery-2.2.0.min.js ) and this is working fine please suggest something else

Comment: hey #gerrytan i have placed .js file in '/resources/js/jquery-1.11.1.min.js' but the thing is .css is also placed in same dir and it is working fine problem is only with the .js file